# Ajax State, City Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a program that when you select a state from the drop down menu, it will display the list of cities for that state in another drop down menu that you can select from. After you choose your city and state, you type in an address, hit submit, and it will display the full address on a new php file.

My issue at the moment is I can get the states displayed, but when the state is selected, it is not giving me the list of options for that city in the second drop down menu. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

You can view the behavior at this [link](https://web.njit.edu/~csg25/download/select.php)

select.php

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action = "display.php">
<script type="text/javascript">


function fetch_select(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="heading">Address Generator</p>
<center>
<div id="select_box">
 <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
  <option>Select state</option>


  <?php
  include (  "accounts.php"     ) ;
( $dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password ) )
            or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
print "Connected to MySQL<br>";
mysql_select_db( $project ); 

  $select=mysql_query("select state from zipcodes group by state");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
   echo "<option>".$row['state']."</option>";
  }
 ?>
 </select>

 <select id="new_select">
 </select>

<div id='2'> </div>
<br><br>
<input type = text name="address">Address
<br><br>
<input type = submit>

</form>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
include(accounts.php);
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
 ( $dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password ) )
            or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
print "Connected to MySQL<br>";
mysql_select_db( $project );


 $state = $_POST['get_option'];
 $find=mysql_query("select city from zipcodes where state='$state'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
  echo "<option>".$row['city']."</option>";
 }
 exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: what the ajax response return can you check it with console

Comment: first of all your state option's value attribute is missing  echo "<option value='".$row['state']."'>".$row['state']."</option>";

Comment: and include(accounts.php);   accounts.php should be enclosed by double quotes

Comment: @JYoThI Where would I insert that line of code? I apologize if this is a dumb question but I'm fairly new at working with AJAX

Comment: state option inside the while loop

Comment: Alright I replaced    echo "<option>".$row['state']."</option>";   with your code, however it still did not change the behavior. Thanks for the help btw I really appreciate it

Comment: first of all check that fetch_select function calling or not on change . alert(val);  inside the function start .

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all your state option's value attribute is missing

```
echo "<option value='".$row["state"]."'>".$row["state"]."</option>";
```

2)Include(accounts.php); `accounts.php` should be enclosed by double quotes

3) And city option's value attribute is missing

```
echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'>".$row["city"]."</option>";
```

4) Instead of echoing each time concatenate and echo finally like this

```
$options="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
     $options.= "<option value='".$row["city"]."' >".$row["city"]."</option>";
  }

 echo $options;
```

**Warning!!!**

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Thank you! i've done all this and still the city drop down menu will not show any cities when I select a state. For example, if I select "New Jersey", the city drop down menu should display three options, "Newark, Bloomfield, Edison"

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a little. Tried to do it the elegant way. You had wrote too much of superfluous code. You didn't need a `<form>` element to perform the asked operation. Anyway below is the modified code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Address Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="heading">Address Generator</p>
    <center>
    <!-- <div id="select_box"> -->
    <select name="select_box" id="select_box">

        <?php
            include (  "accounts.php"     ) ;
            ( $dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password ) ) or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
            print "Connected to MySQL<br>";
            mysql_select_db( $project ); 
            $select=mysql_query("select state from zipcodes group by state");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
            {
                echo "<option>".$row['state']."</option>";
            }
         ?>            
    </select>
    <select id="new_select">

    </select>
    <div id='2'> </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type = text name="address">Address
    <br><br>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#select_box').on('change', function() {
                var state = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'fetch.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {state: state},
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        var response = JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#new_select').find('option').remove();
                        var option = '';
                        $.each(response.cities, function(key, val) {
                          option = option + "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>";
                        });
                          $('#new_select').append(option);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

1. I've added Jquery before the end of `</body>` tag. This doesn't hinder your current code execution. However you could always preload it but that tactic is for later.
2. Since you didn't need any `<form>` element so I've completely removed it. You can always add it according to your convenience.
3. I'm running a loop on the `cities` array of the object `response` that I'm getting from `fetch.php`.
4. parsing the JSON data using `JSON.parse()` function.
5. You'll need to `json_encode` your json variable which will store the corresponding citites data.

I hope this helps. Any further queries are welcome too.